# Fazer JSON.parse nas propriedades do Objeto

Tags: javascript

Ajuda para criar uma função Javascript que recebe um objeto e percorre seus registros e atributos para fazer o JSON.parse no valor do atributo caso seja necessário? (como identificar se é JSON? pensei em ler os 2 primeiros caracteres '[{' e os 2 ultimos '}]' para identificar)
Exemplo do Objeto:

```
[{
    funcionarios: 3,
    grupo: "[{\"idGrupo\":1,\"nome\":\"TESTE\"}]",
    idColaborador: 474,
    idColaboradorResponsavel: 474,
    segmento: "[{\"idSegmento\":1,\"nome\":\"PRETO\"}]"
}, {
    funcionarios: 1,
    grupo: "[{\"idGrupo\":2,\"nome\":\"TESTE2\"}]",
    idColaborador: 2,
    idColaboradorResponsavel: 3,
    segmento: "[{\"idSegmento\":4,\"nome\":\"AZUL\"}]"
}];
```

Preciso identificar os atributos grupo e segmento pois vou recuperar o valor deles e fazer um JSON.parse no seu conteúdo, transformando em um novo objeto...
Estes dados vem de um webservice então podem existir N atributos que vao precisar receber o PARSE

Comment: Olá Carlos! O que queres dizer com _"caso seja necessário"_? Sabes de antemão quais as propriedades que são JSONs?

Comment: Duas dúvidas: uma é a mesma do Sergio, como você sabe quais são JSON eu quais não são? A outra dúvida é, o que você já tentou até agora, tem código?

Comment: Olá Pessoal, este objeto é retornado do webservice, estes dados vem lá do SQL Server, pensei em identificar quais são JSON observando os 2 primeiros '[{' e 2 ultimos caracteres '}]', já tentei fazer um FOR e tbm forEach mas não consegui percorer os atributos, ler seu valor e identificar se deve fazer o PARSE ou não.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O ideal seria saber de antemão quais as propriedades que você quer fazer parse, senão você irá ter que tentar fazer o parse de todas as strings, e não tem como saber se ela é um JSON ou não só pelas chaves e colchetes, você tem que analisar a sintaxe da string inteira.

```js
    var data = [{
        funcionarios: 3,
        grupo: "[{\"idGrupo\":1,\"nome\":\"TESTE\"}]",
        idColaborador: 474,
        idColaboradorResponsavel: 474,
        segmento: "[{\"idSegmento\":1,\"nome\":\"PRETO\"}]"
    }, {
        funcionarios: 1,
        grupo: "[{\"idGrupo\":2,\"nome\":\"TESTE2\"}]",
        idColaborador: 2,
        idColaboradorResponsavel: 3,
        segmento: "[{\"idSegmento\":4,\"nome\":\"AZUL\"}]"
    }];

    for (var obj of data) {
      for (var key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'string') {
          try {
            obj[key] = JSON.parse(obj[key]);
          } catch (err) { }
        }
      }
    }

    console.log(data);
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu meu problema.
obs: no meu caso todos que são JSON vem com chaves e colchetes